Multiple dispatch based on object attribute types in python with multimethod
I'm a Python noob having a tough time trying to implement multiple dispatch (based on object attributes types) using multimethod.
To be more precise, as long as I use functions this works lovely


from dataclasses import dataclass
from multimethod import multimethod

@multimethod
def disp(a, b):
    print("dunno")
    
@multimethod
def disp(a: int, b: None):
    print("int x none")

@multimethod
def disp(a: str, b: None):
    print("str x none")

@multimethod
def disp(a: int, b: str):
    print("int x str")

@multimethod
def disp(a: str, b: str):
    print("str x str")


disp(None, None) # dunno
disp(1, None)    # int x none
disp("test", None) # str x none
disp(1, "test")    # int x str
disp("test", "test") # str x str

However when it comes to methods I get only dunnos
@dataclass
class Test:
    x: int|str
    y: int|str|None = None
    
    def do(self):
        self._dispatch(a = self.x, b = self.y)

    @multimethod
    def _dispatch(self, a, b): # default case
        print("dunno")

    @multimethod
    def _dispatch(self, a: int, b: None):
        print("int x none")

    @multimethod
    def _dispatch(self, a: str, b: None):
        print("str x none")

    @multimethod
    def _dispatch(self, a: int, b: str):
        print("int x str")

    @multimethod
    def _dispatch(self, a: str, b: str):
        print("str x str")

    # etc..

## what is printed is always the default case
t1 = Test(1)
type(t1.x)
t1.y is None
t1.do() # should be int x none
Test("test").do()  # should be str x none
Test(1, "test").do()  # should be int x str
Test("test", "test").do()  # should be str x str

What am I missing/doing wrong? Thanks

I don't know what is wrong, but I changed the do() method to call like this: self._dispatch(self.x, self.y) and it seemed to work.

@quamrana thank you so much, using the positional not named call actually fix it to me too!
